# How to Create a Nested JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I already read Create nested JSON from csv, but it didn't help in my case.

I would like to create a json from an excel spreadsheet using python. the code below generates a dic then a json, however i would like to revise the code further so that i can get the following json.
I have had no luck so far.

**Desired outcome**:

> {"items": {
>       "AMS Upgrade": [
>         {"Total": "30667"},
>         {"% Complete to end": "100%"},
>         {"value claimed": "25799"}
>       ],   "BMS works": [
>         {"Total": "35722"},
>         {"% Complete to end": "10%"},
>         {"value claimed": "3572"}
>       ] }}

**Current outcome**:

> {"line items": {"AMS Upgrade": "30667", "BMS Modification": "35722"}}

**Current code:**

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("Example - supporting doc.xls")
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(-1)
nested_dict = {}


nested_dict["line items"] = {}
for i in range(21,175):
    Line_items = first_sheet.row_slice(rowx=i, start_colx=2, end_colx=8)

    if str(Line_items[0].value) and str(Line_items[1].value):
        if not Line_items[5].value ==0 : 
            print str(Line_items[0].value)
            print str(Line_items[5].value)
            nested_dict["line items"].update({str(Line_items[0].value) : str(Line_items[1].value)})

print  nested_dict

print json.dumps(nested_dict)
```

**Excel print out:**
[image]

Comment: Where's the data?

Comment: sorry, i did revise the code to original, ignore original

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create nested JSON from CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043229/create-nested-json-from-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("Example - supporting doc.xls")
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(-1)
nested_dict = {}

nested_dict["line items"] = {}
col_names = {1: "Total", 2: "% Complete to end", 5: "value claimed"}

for i in range(21,175):
    Line_items = first_sheet.row_slice(rowx=i, start_colx=2, end_colx=8)

    if str(Line_items[0].value) and str(Line_items[1].value):
        if not Line_items[5].value ==0 :
            inner_list = []
            for j in [1, 2, 5]:
                inner_list.append({col_names[j]: Line_items[j].value})
            nested_dict["line items"].update({str(Line_items[0].value) : inner_list})

print(nested_dict)

print(json.dumps(nested_dict))
```